# Checking null object in react js with graphql query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null, graphql

I am new to the react and graphql . here, I have a query and I want to check the null data.

```
return (
      <Query
        query={Report}
        variables={{
          id: match.params.pId
        }}
        {({ loading, error, data: gdata }) => {
          if (loading) return <Loader />
          if (error) return <Error />
          return <Report data={gdata && gdata.greport} />
        }}
      </Query>
```

So, I checking null using this way or

```
data: gdata = { gdata: {} } })
```

In which way should I check for the null or empty data as it gets crashed .And also if it is an array. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am checking the result on my project using ternary

if its an array

```
gData ? gData.greport : []
```

if its an object

```
gData ? gData.greport : {}
```

Comment: and what about in render like gdata && gdata.report  or gdata && gdata.length > 0 && gdat.report